# How to add multiple values to list C#

Tags: c#

Hi I have the following code when I am adding values to a list.

```
var NoLiftingList = new List<SQLFields>();

SQLFields nolifting = new SQLFields();
nolifting.Field1 = "No lifting";
NoLiftingList.Add(nolifting);

SQLFields extremelifting = new SQLFields();
extremelifting.Field1 = "Up to 100 lbs (extreme lifting)";
NoLiftingList.Add(extremelifting);
```

How can I simplify this? Instead of initializing a new object all the time.

This is the code for the whole class updated below.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Object Initializers with anonymous types

```
var NoLiftingList = new List<SQLFields>(){ 
               new SQLFields() { Field1 = "No lifting"}, 
               new SQLFields() { Field1 = "Up to 100 lbs (extreme lifting)"}
};
```

Ref: [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Comment: This is not an anonymous object.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for works great and very clean. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add to a list, and set properties on a class by using this inline constructor syntax (working example):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var NoLiftingList = new List<SQLFields>
        {
            new SQLFields
            {
                Field1 = "No Lifting"
            },
            new SQLFields
            {
                Field1 = "Up to 100lbs (extreme lifting)"
            }           
        };
    }
}

public class SQLFields
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var NoLiftingList = new List<SQLFields>()
{
    new SQLFields()
    {
        Field1 = "No lifting"
    },
    new SQLFields()
    {
        Field1 = "Up to 100 lbs (extreme lifting)"
    }
};
```